# Different between two variables in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone explain the different between two variables `a1` and `a2`:

```
app.controller("someCtrl",function(){
  this.a1=somevalue;
  var a2=somevalue;
});
```

And what lifetime `a2` has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are similar. Same lifetime however this.a1 has model bindings (which is fundamental within angular applications if you're going to use this variable anywhere in your view) where as a2 doesn't and you won't be able to access it using $scope within the view.

Comment: I don't using $scope at all. So as I understand, all the different is a1 is available in view, and a2 doesn't, right?

Comment: Yes. That's basically all. this inherits controller properties too i.e. it can be accessed in $rootScope etc. If you don't need to access it anywhere except that controller I would stick to var declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Simply speaking, `this.a1` will create a property called `a1` on whatever object `this` refers to when invoking the controller function. Since you are invoking the constructor function, `this` will refer to the controller itself, so you will be able to use `a1` for data-binding. `var a2` will create a local variable called `a2` inside the function.

Comment: but if in this context this refers to the controller?

Comment: Yes, it is the controller instance.